# moving the caption of a tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tooltip

Can somebody please tell me how to arrange the caption above the image in the jsfiddle below as I can not seem to do it. The caption is currently below the image. Thanks in advance.

[Sample Code](http://jsfiddle.net/k62NY/4/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $("ul.thumb li").hover(function() {
  $(this)
    .css('z-index', '10')
    .find('img').addClass("hover")
    .stop()
    .animate({
       marginTop: '-150px',
       marginLeft: '-150px',
       top: '50%',
       left: '50%',
       width: '300px',
       height: '300px',
       padding: '20px'

     }, 200, function() {

        var $this = $(this),
        h = $this.height();
        $caption = $('<div class="caption">' + this.title  + '</div>')
            .css('top', h.toString() + 'px');
            $this.after($caption);

      }); 

   }, function() {

 $('.caption').remove();
 $(this)
.css('z-index', '0')
.find('img').removeClass("hover")
.stop()
.animate({

    marginTop: '0',
    marginLeft: '0',
    top: '0',
    left: '0',
    width: '200px',
    height: '200px',
    padding: '5px'

 }, 400);
});
});
</script>
```

I hope this helps

Comment: I can't help but notice a slight disparity between your *demo* and your *posted code* here in the question. We ask for a *[minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/)*, not the entirety of your project, for a reason: it helps to clarify the problem. If you can't be bothered to play by the rules why should we take the time to help?

Comment: @DavidThomas just thought that duplicating the code was wasting everybodies time, my apologies, I do not know which part of the code to post as I do not know where the problem lies... so I assumed if I posted the JS, CSS and HTML via a jsfiddle this would solve the issue. I shall try to work out which part of the code I should be posting and post it. again my apologies

Comment: @DavidThomas Could you please take a look and help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an updated [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/k62NY/19/).

The relevant line is this one:

```
.css('top', -h.toString() + 'px');
```

It positions the div for the text, and to change the position above the image, I just placed a negative sign in front of h.toString(). You could finely adjust the position by multiplying the h.toString() by a coefficient like -.8 or -.92 to make finer adjustments. It may be problematic putting it above the image, because you'll have to adjust the position based on the height of the text div.